# Why would the SO developers use `document.write`?

Tags: discussion, javascript, system-message

This is a spin off of this question: [Why is the SO system message written in by javascript?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114058/155556)

Why would they use `document.write`?

Current Code on page:

```
<div id="system-message-temp">

<script type="text/javascript">

    var curSystemMessage = 'SOPA is a dangerous law. It breaks the Internet and threatens sites like Stack Overflow. <a href="http:\/\/americancensorship.org\/" rel="nofollow">Protect the Internet<\/a>!';

    document.write(curSystemMessage); //WHAT? Why....?

    $('#system-message-temp').attr('id', 'system-message');

</script>

</div>
```

Why didn't they totally drop that and use jQuery?

```
<div id="system-message-temp">

<script type="text/javascript">

    var curSystemMessage = 'SOPA is a dangerous law. It breaks the Internet and threatens sites like Stack Overflow. <a href="http:\/\/americancensorship.org\/" rel="nofollow">Protect the Internet<\/a>!';

    $('#system-message-temp').html(curSystemMessage).attr('id', 'system-message');

</script>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh dear, I hope this doesn't start a jQuery flame war...

Comment: @Shad it doesn't :-D

Comment: Uhm... why not? Also, this sounds more like a Stack Overflow question to me.

Comment: @balpha I am asking about SO. you don't ask about SO on SO :-P

Comment: `Why didn't they totally drop that and use jQuery?`...and I who thought that memes where funny exaggerations... http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/163321

Comment: @DamienPirsy hehe who mem-fied my Q? :-P

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama: hehe...me :)

Comment: Yay for palindromic usernames!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Originally the system messages was set via jQuery, but "flashed" unpleasantly.  Using `document.write` avoided this.

Now, the old jQuery code was last tested more than a year ago (a few jQuery versions ago, and many of the then supported browsers are no longer supported) so this may no longer be a valid concern.  However, the code works so we've had no reason to revisit it since it was written.

Comment: +1 seems like a valid answer, I can't verify but I remember we had something similiar due to jQuery flashing. If it ain't broke don't fix it...or something like that :-).

Comment: This is still an issue, as people complaining about the flashing of questions with ignored tags will confirm :-)

Comment: (and yes, I know that's nowadays happening in a lazy-loaded JS file, but with the file being in the cache, that doesn't matter)